# Split Active Admin index into two tables/panels based on a field

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I want to do something like this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Split do
  index do
    panel "Cute" do
      if cute?
        column :blah
        default_actions
      end
    end
    panel "Not so cute" do
      if not cute?
        column :toot
        default_actions
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Where there's the `Cute` table which lists all the objects which `cute?` is true and then there's the `Not so cute` table where `cute?` is false.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to split it into two different tables/panels.  I'm getting the following error:

```
undefined method `column' for                 <div class="index_as_table"></div>
:ActiveAdmin::Views::IndexAsTable
```

Which leads me to believe I shouldn't be using `panel` above `column`.  I searched through the ActiveAdmin docs and couldn't find anything about splitting the index table view into two tables

Answer (score 0):

The closest solution I know of, is using two different tabs (one for each panel) which is done automatically when setting scopes in activeadmin.

```
# app/admin/splits.rb
  scope :cute,    :default => true
  scope :not_cute

# app/models/splits.rb
  scope :cute,     where(:cute=> true)
  scope :not_cute, where(:cute => false)
```